# Spring web socket - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [message-broker]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I'm trying to add the spring-websocket dependency in a Spring web app.

I have added this dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have created an XML configuration equivalent for @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker, as indicated here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-enable

So, I have this spring-socket-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket.xsd">

    <websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
        <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/myPath">
            <websocket:sockjs/>
        </websocket:stomp-endpoint>
        <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic, /queue"/>
    </websocket:message-broker>

</beans>
```

When I start the web-app, I immediately have this error:

```
[ERROR] 2016-07-04 14:52:11,381 [] []  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [message-broker]
```

How to solve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same error as you.

It turns out that you will need **spring-messaging** jar in the class path in order to use **websocket:message-broker** in the xml.

The error message is not helpful at all